# Hide status bar in not working in some device

Tags: android

*Hide status bar* is not working in **Pixel-2-api24**. However it's working fine in **Pixel-3a-XL-api29**.
here is the code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        window.decorView.systemUiVisibility = (View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
    }
}
```

**Pixel-2-api24** Screenshot

[image]

**Pixel-3a-XL-api29** Screenshot

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

For hiding status bar you need to change your app theme :

```
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowDisablePreview">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
        <!--<item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorAccent</item>-->
    </style>
```

Also add below line in your activity oncreate:

```
 supportActionBar?.hide()
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the default available UI flags for Full screen activity?

```
// Note that some of these constants are new as of API 16 (Jelly Bean)
// and API 19 (KitKat). It is safe to use them, as they are inlined
// at compile-time and do nothing on earlier devices.
window.decorView.systemUiVisibility =
    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
```

And the default style for this:

```
<style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/FullscreenActionBarStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarStyle</item>
    <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="FullscreenActionBarStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/black_overlay</item>
</style>
```

You can check it by yourself by creating a new FullScreen activity in your app or in a sample project. It also provides you a way to delay the hiding of system bars and to toggle them. It is also very well commented.